# Drawing triangles given user input

Tags: c#, trigonometry, system.drawing

So I'm trying to make a Program that will draw a triangle given some user input. The variables that the user provides are angleA, angleB, andleC, and the corresponding sides. The code I have set up to find the three points of the angle is as follows.

```
double angle_A = double.Parse(angleA.Text);
double angle_B = double.Parse(angleB.Text);
double angle_C = double.Parse(angleC.Text);
double side_A = double.Parse(sideA.Text);
double side_B = double.Parse(sideB.Text);
double side_C = double.Parse(sideC.Text);

double triangleHeight = Area * 2 / (double.Parse(sideB.Text));
double height = canvas.Height;
double width = canvas.Width;

int aX, aY, bX, bY, cX, cY; 

aY = Convert.ToInt32(canvas.Height - triangleHeight / 2);

if (angle_A <= 90 && angle_C <= 90)
{
    aX = Convert.ToInt32((width - side_B) / 2);
}
else if (angle_A > 90)
{
    double extraLength = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(side_C, 2) - Math.Pow(triangleHeight, 2));
    aX = Convert.ToInt32(width - ((width - (side_B + extraLength)) / 2) + side_B);
}
else if (angle_C > 90)
{
    double extraLength = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(side_A, 2) - Math.Pow(triangleHeight, 2));
    aX = Convert.ToInt32((width - side_B + extraLength) / 2);
}
else
{
    aX = 0;
    MessageBox.Show("ERROR: No such triangle exists", "ERROR:");
}

cX = aX + Convert.ToInt32(side_B);
cY = aY;

bX = Convert.ToInt32(side_A * Math.Cos(Math.PI * angle_C / 180) + cX);
bY = Convert.ToInt32(side_A * Math.Sin(Math.PI * angle_C / 180) - cY);

Point pointA = new Point(aX, aY);
Point pointB = new Point(bX, bY);
Point pointC = new Point(cX, cY);
Point[] points = new Point[3] { pointA, pointB, pointC };

return points;
```

This returns the three points that the paint method should use to draw the triangle. However, when I insert the values, the triangle it draws looks nothing like the triangle I have described with the user input. Any thoughts on why this is? Thanks in advance.

P.S. The error is not in my code, as it gives me no errors and does not crash. It is strictly a math error that I have not been able to locate.

Comment: Looks like you have confused side names and points. Try to use aX and aY for calculations of bx and by. And your calculations of ax is just misleading. You can assume that A has a fixed coordinates, then B would be the same as it is already and C - somwhere :) And your condition for existance of that triangle is wrong as well

Comment: It sounds like you're asking for a lot of trouble be allowing the user so many inputs - what happens if they don't actually supply input that's *consistent*? A triangle can be defined by one length and two angles, or two lengths and one angle.

Comment: Or three sides @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine the triangle ABC with corners A and C along the base line with A to the left and C to the right, and B somewhere above them.  Side A is the side opposite corner A, and so on.

As Damien_the_Unbeliever says, you should only allow input of, say, side B, side C and angle of corner A.  Validate that A is not over 180 degrees.  Start off with A at the origin, so we know straight away that xA = 0, yA = 0, xC = length of side B, yC=0, xB = side C * cos A, and yB = side C * sin A.  I believe this works even if A is over 90 degrees, you do get a negative value for xB but don't worry, continue anyway!

Now all you have to do is centre the triangle on the canvas. I don't understand where you are getting Area from.  It makes no sense to calculate the triangle's height from its area. The triangle height is yB, you can calculate the offset you need to centre it vertically as you know, so long as yB <= height.  Add the same y offset to all the points.

The horizontal offset is a bit more complicated!  If xB is negative, I would add an offset to all the x values to bring xB to 0, this positions your triangle at the left side of the canvas, and its width is given by the new xC.  If xB is non-negative, the width is the maximum of xC or xB.  Then you can calculate the x offset from the width as you know.

I have had time to do some of the code, for example values; this will draw a triangle but not yet centre it:

```
int sideB = 100;
int sideC = 143;
int angleA = 28;
double angleARadians = Math.PI * angleA / 180.0;

int[] xs = new int[3];
int[] ys = new int[3];

//1st corner is at the origin
xs[0] = 0; ys[0] = 0;

//Then the third corner is along the x axis from there to the length of side B

xs[2] = sideB; ys[2] = 0;

// The second corner is up a bit above the x axis.  x could be negative.
```

// Note, when you draw it, the y axis extends downwards, so a positive y value will be drawn below the x axis.

```
    xs[1] = (int)Math.Round(sideC * Math.Cos(angleARadians));
    ys[1] = (int)Math.Round(sideC * Math.Sin(angleARadians));

 //If Bx is negative, move all the points over until it's 0

    if (xs[1] < 0)
    {
        int zeroX = xs[1] * -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            xs[i] += zeroX;
        }
    }

    // Now centre the triangle on the canvas.
    // Firstly find the width of the triangle.  Point B could be to the left of A, or between A and C, or to the right of C.
    // So the left most point of the triangle is the minimum of A or B, and the right most point is the maximum of B or C.
    int minX = Math.Min(xs[0],xs[1]);
    int maxX = Math.Max(xs[2], xs[1]);

    //The height of the triangle is yB.

    int offsetX = (panCanvas.Width - (maxX - minX)) / 2;
    int offsetY = (panCanvas.Height - ys[1]) / 2;

    //offset all the points by the same amount, to centre the triangle.
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        xs[i] += offsetX;
        ys[i] += offsetY;
    }
```

Comment: So I tried this, and it didn't work. My cod to define the points is now:
    aY = Convert.ToInt32(canvas.Height);
            aX = 0;

            cX = Convert.ToInt32(side_B);
            cY = 0;

            bX = Convert.ToInt32(side_C * Math.Cos(angle_A) * (180 / Math.PI));
            bY = Convert.ToInt32(side_C * Math.Sin(angle_A) * (180 / Math.PI));

The reason I have aY = canvas.height is because the 0, 0 point is in the top left corner, not the bottom left. But that did not work at all.
As for the issue of user input, I have taken measures to make sure everything is consistent.

Comment: I'm sorry, I had forgotten that your origin is in the top left and all your coordinates have to be down and to the right of that!  Is it OK if the triangle comes out pointing downwards?

I was really just outlining an approach, e.g. 1. Calculate the corners of the triangle relative to each other, and keep it simple by having one corner at (0,0) and a horizontal base.  (2) Then move the triangle to where you need it by applying the same offset to all the x coordinates, and an offset to all the y coordinates.

I would like to code it for you but I will be busy until Thursday.

Comment: If you are going to move aY down, you have to move cY down by the same amount.

By the way, you have got your formula for converting degrees to radians upside down in your comment.  You had it right before!

Answer (score 0):

Given the three sides of a triangle *a*, *b*, and *c* the coordinates of the vertices are

```
P=[0,0]
Q=[a,0]
R=[(a^2+c^2-b^2)/(2*a), sqrt(c^2*(2*(a^2+b^2)-c^2)-(a+b)^2*(a-b)^2)/(4*a^2))]
```

Example, *a*=6, *b*=4 and *c*=8

```
P=[0,0]
Q=[6,0]
R=[7,√15]
```

[image: pic]

Comment: I`m not sure if on your image a == c